# How to format a specific string of data in PHP?

Tags: php, database, string, explode

So, I have a .txt file full of data of uses of a program on my site. The format goes as follows:

```
~input|methodUsed|User|userInfo|month|day|year|hour|minute\n
```

Every time someone uses the program, it adds this line to the text file. I'm working on a statistics page. I'm wondering three things:

How to manage the string of the entries (using file_get_contents) to:

Get the uses in a specific day (say `08|17|17`)

In  that day, get the most common user and/or input

And overall, get the most common user and/or input

I assume the difference in code between finding the most common user and the most common input is hardly any. Can anybody help me accomplish any, or all three of these tasks in PHP? I'm aware of PHP's explode() function and assume that is necessary to complete this task. I know this way of handling data is not the best, but I really do not want to change it. I have months of data stored this way. If I failed to add any information necessary to complete the task, please let me know.

Comment: Too broad.  Isolate your issue.  Show your coding attempt.  Show some sample input.

Comment: Use a database, even temporarily, with LOAD DATA INFILE - to make this workable without copious amounts of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mario was suggesting, you could easily put the data in a database, and it would make it really simple to get the stats you are looking for. I'll show you  an example of doing this with an SQLite3 database.

First, you'd want to import your data. You could use `file_get_contents`, but because I had to test this, I just imported it from a string, and because I didn't know what your data really looks like, I just made it up:

```
$db = new SQLite3( __DIR__ . '/logs.db');
$db->exec('
    CREATE TABLE log (
        input TEXT,
        methodUsed TEXT,
        User TEXT,
        userInfo TEXT,
        datetime TEXT
    )
');

$str = "~a|3|Bob|aaa|12|04|2000|23|05\n
~b|6|Bill|bbb|08|18|2017|14|18\n
~c|4|Tina|ccc|09|28|2016|16|33\n
~d|7|Doug|ddd|11|07|2017|08|24\n
~e|1|Fred|eee|01|22|2015|00|16\n";

// Get an array of lines
$lines = explode( PHP_EOL, $str );

// Loop through the lines
foreach( $lines as $line )
{
    if( ! empty( $line ) )
    {
        list(
            $input,
            $methodUsed,
            $User,
            $userInfo,
            $month,
            $day,
            $year,
            $hour,
            $minute
        ) = explode( '|', $line );

        $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($year . '/' . $month . '/' . $day . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $minute . ':00' ) );

        $db->exec("
            INSERT INTO log (input, methodUsed, User, userInfo, datetime) 
            VALUES (\"$input\",\"$methodUsed\",\"$User\",\"$userInfo\",\"$dateTime\")
        ");
    }
}
```

Now that there's a database with data in it, it's really easy to do the queries to give you the stats you want. You get a connection again:

```
$db = new SQLite3( __DIR__ . '/logs.db');
```

This just selects all the users in each row

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT User FROM log');
```

This selects all from all rows where the datetime is in the last 6 months

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM log WHERE datetime > datetime("now", "-6 months")');
```

This selects all from all rows where the datetime is on a specific day

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM log WHERE date(datetime) = "2017-08-18"');
```

Get most common user on a specific day

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT User, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM log WHERE date(datetime) = "2017-08-18" GROUP BY User ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1');
```

Get the most common user of all records

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT *, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM log GROUP BY User ORDER BY cnt LIMIT 1');
```

Finally, display the results of any of the results above (choose 1 at a time):

```
while( $row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) )
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $row );
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

I'm sure you'd want to make your own modifications, or perhaps use a MySQL database instead (which is what I'd do), but this ought to get you started. I did test this code, so it should meet your needs, if you are considering this type of thing.

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifully... I edited some of the code to make it work for my data (like my year is '17' not '2017', so I had to add a 20 in front of the year variable to make it now show the date as January 1, 1970. I figured out how to add new data to the existing database, but I was wondering one more thing. How could I count the amount of uses in one day? @brianGottier

Comment: Never mind, I found a different question with that answer. My statistics script works perfectly now, thanks again.